# Best way to connect to own cloud with Rest Api from Power BI?

Tags: rest, powerbi

we have a cloud solution where data is available through a Rest Api. We want to connect to this from Power BI.

We tried to develop a custom connector, and it worked well from within Power BI Desktop. But it fell short on the limit that custom connectors cannot be set up for automatic refresh in Power BI services. And we'd rather not need to use a Gateway, as we have several different customers in our cloud solution - and we'd need one Gateway for each if I understand it correctly.

So I wonder: what would be the best way to set up a connection to create reports from this Api, that would support automatic refresh?

We would ideally like our tables to be selectable in full after the connection is made (i.e. we don't want one connection per table).

Do we need to support full OAuth for this?

Could using the OData connector help?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: I also use a custom connector with an on-premises gateway. I don't know another way to schedule refreshes, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you looked any at the Web Connector? I don't quite get the use case for it - are we supposed to fetch one type of data for each Web Connector data source? That doesn't quite seem viable.

Comment: Web connector isn't the same as Custom Connector?
I use a connector that requests the data I need whenever I chose to. For refreshes it has to be a data gateway. The connector supports OAuth2.0

Comment: With custom connectors I mean what we develop.
There are pre-made connectors, like the Web Connector, or maybe even more interesting, the OData connector that seems to be able to retrieve data from a web service in a structured format. 

Not a lot of examples on how to make an existing web api support OData though. Most I see are using Entity Framework where you can make an OData service "for free".

I don't know if you also develop the web api?

Comment: You can also retrieve the data from web services in structured formats with custom connectors. They can implement the same logic as the pre-made Web Connectors. You can set the datasets to refresh and implement OAuth. For cloud refreshes you'll need that gateway help but it works fine.